# Obtain absolute path on image ckeditor + django + react

Tags: reactjs, django, ckeditor

**Django**

There are 2 question about this topic, but both of them (this is one [Absolute paths on images uploaded by django-ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61325006/absolute-paths-on-images-uploaded-by-django-ckeditor)) are not updated. For example, in Django 4.X, url was removed. Despite this, I've tried these solutions, but no one worked for me.

I've also tried to use:

`CKEDITOR_MEDIA_PREFIX` on my settings.py

But it didn't work either.
This is my **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

This is my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/news/', include('news.urls')),
    re_path(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        }),
]
```

So here is my question, how can I set up my Django-rest-framework app in such way that I get the absolute path when I render the html on my `next.js` site?

This is what I get right now:

```
<img alt=\"\" src=\"/media/uploads/2022/01/19/video.svg\"/>
```

This is what I'd like to get:

```
<img alt=\"\" src=\"http://website.com/media/uploads/2022/01/19/video.svg\"
```

**React**
Is there any way to achieve these from the frontend? For example, updating all img's src

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quick solution (I'm pretty sure this is not the "right" way of doing this), here is my approach:

As I only need to update the `img.src` in one JavaScript file, I did it using a hook to get all the images, filter only those ones that are stored in the server and update their src.

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        
        //! Don´t forget to update this
        const imgDomain = 'https://...'; 

        const imgStore = document.querySelectorAll("img[src]");
        Object.keys(imgStore).map((x)=>{

            if(imgStore[x].src.includes('uploads')){
                const originalURL = imgStore[x].src;
               var mediaPos =  originalURL.indexOf('/media/');
               var URLlength = originalURL.length;
               var slicedSRC = originalURL.slice (mediaPos, URLlength);
               var newSRC = imgDomain+slicedSRC;
               imgStore[x].src = newSRC;

            }
        })
        
    }, []);
```